# Add metadata to xml created with jgraph

Tags: java

I use `JGraph` for Java to create graphic representation of Petri net and then export it to XML. Is there any method, which add to xml my own text? I need to create there something like metadata, specifically, who created network, when and so on.

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: Change your XML and try to import it and see the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store some data in parent node (note that this is untested):

```
((mxCell) ((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell("0") ).setAttribute("tagname", "your");
```

If storing one string is enough for you, this definitely works:

```
((mxCell) ((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell("0") ).setValue("your text");
String text = (String) ((mxCell) ((mxGraphModel)graph.getModel()).getCell("0") ).getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following and it works.

- Create a graph
- Save it to XML
- Open the XML using notepad and change some text values
- In JGraph, import the updated file
- The drawings should show the updated text